# How to capture the data from 2 different tables in database?

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
function getdetails() {

        // define URL
        var url = serverURL() + "/eventbyids.php";
        // pass userid as JSON objects

        itemitemid = decodeURIComponent(getUrlVars()["eventid"]);

        var JSONObject = {
            "eventid": decodeURIComponent(getUrlVars()["eventid"])
        };

        // Call Ajax
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            data: JSONObject,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (arr) {
             **// this the part where i having the problem**  
                $.ajax({
                    url: serverURL() + "/getorgname.php",
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: JSONObject1,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (arr) {

                        var orgname = arr[0].orgname;

                        $('#detailsmain1').append(orgname);
                        alert("123");

                    },

                    error: function () {
                        alert("error45");
                    }




                });


                    var eventid = arr[0].eventid;
                    var orgid = arr[0].userid;
                    var eventname = arr[0].eventname;

                    var JSONObject1 = {
                        "userid": orgid
                    };
            },

            error: function () {
                alert("error");
            }

        });
```

The orgname cannot be capture from the database. (2nd ajax call)
(The userid is the same as the original) 
For example, I want to GET org name from different table in the database. We are calling ajax within another ajax, however we are still unable to capture the org name.

[image: tables in the database]

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

```
$.when( $.ajax( "/page1.php" ), $.ajax( "/page2.php" ) ).done(function( a1, a2 ) {
  // a1 and a2 are arguments resolved for the page1 and page2 ajax requests, respectively.
  // Each argument is an array with the following structure: [ data, statusText, jqXHR ]
  var data = a1[ 0 ] + a2[ 0 ]; // a1[ 0 ] = "Whip", a2[ 0 ] = " It"
  if ( /Whip It/.test( data ) ) {
    alert( "We got what we came for!" );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions would be to create a PHP script that returns the exact data you want.  If this is a possibility.

Make two completely separate AJAX calls to the web server rather than nesting.  With the data from the two calls, combine them into a custom JavaScript object with the properties that you need.